# In android, difference between local-broadcast-receivers , event-bus and rx-bus

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, event-bus

I am confused, can someone explain the difference between local-broadcast-receivers , event-bus and rx-bus and their use cases? Also is there any kotlin based alternative of these?